# Convert data class value into different in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class like this

```
data class BrushStopColors(
    val stopPoint: Float,
    val color: Int,
)
```

I have a list

```
val brushStopColors = listOf(
        BrushStopColors(0.3F, 1),
        BrushStopColors(1F, 1),
    )
```

I want to convert my `color` from `Int` to `String` or any other format. So I tried this code

```
val brushArray = brushStopColors.map { it.color.toString() }
```

And want to change `brushArray` to `.toTypedArray()` and passing into different function. It looks like this

```
fun verticalGradient(vararg colorStops: Pair<Float, String>){
   /// more code in here
}
```

When I passed the array it's giving me error

```
val brushArray = brushStopColors.map { it.color.toString() }.toTypedArray()
verticalGradient(*brushArray)
```

**Error**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Array<out Pair<Float, String>>
Found:
Array<String>
```

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val brushArray = brushStopColors.map { it.color.toString() }
```

The above returns a list of String instead of a list of Pair.

Please use this:

```
fun BrushStopColors.toPair(): Pair<Float, String> = Pair(this.stopPoint, this.color.toString())


val brushArray = brushStopColors.map { it.toPair() }.toTypedArray()
```

Or even more concise :

```
val brushArray = brushStopColors.map { Pair(it.stopPoint, it.color.toString()) }.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the brushArray you'll see that it maps the entire object to a String. I would use an extension function like this:

```
fun BrushStopColors.toGradientPair() = Pair<Float, String>(this.stopPoint, this.color.toString())
```